# Sources needed on Beis Shammai and Mashiach and the paths of the tribes

Tags: sources-mekorot, messiah, shevatim-12-tribes, beis-shammai

Does anyone know where to find the following explanations/sources?

1. ספר השיחות תשנ''א Sefer Hasichos, Shavuos 5751 where the concept is explained of that when Mashiach comes, we will follow Beis Shammai due to the fact that Beis Shammai is the deeper and better understanding of Halacha and when Mashiach comes, our intellect will be elevated.

I'm looking for the sicha in ספר השיחות where the Lubavitcher Rebbe talks on the concept of why we follow Beis Shammai when Mashiach comes.

2. There are twelve gates to the Temple Mount and each tribe represents a unique path to G-d? Are there commentaries that explain this concept?

Thank you!

Comment: Regarding your first question, have you tried Hebrewbooks.org. You can read the Rebbe’s original for free with the footnotes. Regarding your 2nd question, this is printed in the English introduction to Siddur Tehillat HaShem also with source citations. The concept is brought from the Maggid of Mezeritch which can also be viewed there in Sefer Maggid Devarav l’Yaacov.

Comment: @YaacovDeane: My Hebrew is not that good unfortunately (yet). Is the first question explained in https://www.hebrewbooks.org/16035 ? Could you maybe help me to locate it? Also, I found Maggid Devarav leYaakov on Sefaria, do you maybe know where it is stated? I get 41 search results for the word for "tribe". Many thanks!

Comment: Your link is to volume 1. You want the following page from volume 2. https://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=16067&st=&pgnum=131

Comment: Concerning the teachings of the Maggid of Mezeritch, you want the 3 links at the bottom of the following link. https://hebrewbooks.org/home.aspx

Comment: Link was bad. Try this: https://hebrewbooks.org/16062

Comment: And this: https://hebrewbooks.org/19784

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated

Comment: @YaacovDeane: sorry for the question, my Hebrew is not that good yet, where exactly can I find the explanation in Devarav leYaakov?

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/21792/1739

Comment: @mvs The specific section from Sefer Maggid Devarav LeYaacov is Likkutei Amarim, Chapter 133. Here is a link to that page: https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=16062&st=&pgnum=76

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Potential answer to the first question will edit as soon as I have an answer to the 2nd

Source: Sefaria: Mikdash Melech to Zohar Parshat Bereishit 17b

In the time of the Messiah, we will follow the law according to Shammai. Hillel represents kindness and Shammai severity (hence the rulings of Beit Hillel are almost always more lenient). When the Messiah comes the advantage of the severity will be revealed and therefore the law will be in accordance with Beit Shammai. Beit Shammai comes from such a high level this present world is incapable of withstanding it, and only when the Messiah comes will we be able to follow their opinion.

Edit for 2nd Question

As MVS and Yaakov Deane has stated magid davarav l’Yaakov

The Chabad.org quotes the  magid davard l’Yaakov  141 It may then be asked why the other twelve gates were needed, since they are all included in the thirteenth. Why is the thirteenth gate not enough? The answer is, however, that each tribe originally knew its own particular order of prayer, and it was certainly best for each one to enter through its own gate…

Comment: Thank you and looking forward to the second one.

Comment: The explanation about the 13th gate relating to one who doesn’t know their gate is a very subtle way of referring to converts. This is in connection with the idea brought in Talmud and Midrash that all the converts will ultimately comprise the 13th tribe of Israel. This also follows the court decision from Moshe Rabbeinu that converts do not belong to any of the original tribes.

Comment: @YaacovDeane interesting. Did not know this explanation from the Gemara though, where can this be found? Avodah Zarah?

Comment: @mvs See the following link: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/66975/7303

Comment: @mvs See also this link: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/108377/7303

Comment: @YaacovDeane thank you very much!